# Fgets() keeps skipping first character

Tags: c, debugging, fgets

This is part of a larger program to emulate the cat command in unix. Right now trying to take input and send it to stdout:

```
char in[1000];
int c = 0; 
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
 {
   fgets(in,1000,stdin);
   fputs(in, stdout);
 }
```

This sends output to stdout, but in every case it skips the first letter. For instance, if I type the word `Computer`

I get back:

```
omputer
```

Comment: That is because the first character gets stored in getchar()

Comment: You want `while (fgets(in,1000,stdin))` and don't forget to remove the `fgets` in the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: Do instead `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is all about **eating.**

```
c = getchar()
```

This line, as many I/O operations in **C consume your buffer**. Meaning that when you have say `0123456789` after your `getchar()` you're left with `123456789` in your buffer.

What you want to do is use the same functions to control the input and to store it, so something like getting rid of the `getchar()` should do the trick :

```
while (fgets(in,1000,stdin) != NULL)
 {
   fputs(in, stdout);
 }
```

And there you have it !

Answer (score 6):

There is an [`ungetc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ungetc.html) function that allows to return character to a stream. It is not standard C function, but implemented in Unix-like systems and by Visual Studio CRT:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    fgets(in, 1000, stdin);
    fputs(in, stdout);
}
```

But as other answerers note, cleaner way to do that is to use `fgets()` directly:

```
while (fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin) != NULL)
```

The third option is to save first character directly to a string:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    in[0] = c;
    fgets(in + 1, 999, stdin);
    fputs(in, stdout);
}
```

Comment: I did not now about ungetc(), +1 for that

Answer (score 4):

It's not skipping anything you are consuming it with `getchar()`.

Upon successful completion, [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) returns the string `in`. If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and `fgets()` shall return a `NULL` pointer.

Change this

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

to

```
while (fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin) != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too:

```
char in[1000];
while ((in[0] = (char)getchar()) != EOF)
 {
   fgets(in+1,999,stdin);
   fputs(in, stdout);
 }
```

Comment: If `getchar()` returns 255, then with signed `char`, `in[0]` would have the value of `-1`.  This may match `EOF` even though end-of-file did not occur.

Comment: How do you make `getchar()` return 255?

Comment: Many ways.  Example: 1) `FILE * f= fopen("test.txt", "w"); fputc(255, f); fclose(f):`  Now pipe that file into you program "a.bin < text.txt"  2) On many PC keyboard using standard IO: <Alt> key down, <number pad 2>  <number pad 5>  <number pad 5> <Alt> key up.  3) `getchar()`, by spec, returns an `int` in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`.  It does not specify it will not return 255 - so code should be prepared to handle all 257 different values.